# Using helper method and Ruby enumerable to return html formatted objects

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumerable

Apologies for the noob question, but I can't seem to figure out how to return formatted HTML objects using a ruby enumerable and a helper.  I want to remove the brackets. Is there anyway to return formatted objects with an enumerable based on an array of objects?

Helper

```
module PostsHelper


  def display_posts(posts)
    if posts.any?
      raw(@posts.map {|p| raw("<div class='post_text_box'>#{p.body}</div>")})
    end

  end


end
```

HTML.erb

```
<div id="post_feed">
<%=display_posts(@posts)%>

</div>
```

Browser Output

[picture of array of formatted html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0704Q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended you do not `join.html_safe` as the previous answer says, in rails due to the potential for injection attacks if your underlying strings aren't safe.

Use [safe_join](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/safe_join) instead. It will maintain the "safeness" of the strings to output.

```
if posts.any?
  safe_join( @posts.map {|p| "<div class='post_text_box'>#{p.body}</div>".html_safe } )
end
```

In your case I would make a partial named **_post.html.erb** containing

```
<div class='post_text_box'><%= post.body %></div>
```

and in your **thing.html.erb** file

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

Then Rails will automatically iterate `@posts` over `_post.html.erb` and join them for you.

This is all part of [Rails's Convention over configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables), where if you `render klass`, it first looks for `_klass.<format>.<builder>` to render.

Comment: Thanks BookOfGreg.  That's a cool way of doing that.  I've never seen render used like that before.  Do you have a link to explain why that works so I can understand what's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: The bottom of [This section of the Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) mentions how to use rendering with a collection in passing.
It's an extension of Rails's Convention over configuration, like the `show` action looks for `show.html.erb` in it's controller's view folder. Rendering klass looks for _klass.html.erb first.
If you were rendering .json you can render klass in the controller and it would call klass.to_json in the controller to respond.